# How to select records from table_a, if in table_b records connected with table_a has a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL:
**products**

```
id | created_at | updated_at
----------------------------
1  | 10-06-2022 | 11-06-2022
2  | 9-06-2022  | 11-06-2022
```

and **products_meta**

```
id | product_id | key          | value
-----------------------------------------
1  | 1          | status       | enabled
2  | 1          | availability | 50
3  | 1          | name         | Bike
4  | 2          | status       | disabled
5  | 2          | availability | 25
6  | 2          | name         | Rollers
```

etc.

**1. What do I need?**
I need to select all products from `products` table, when each product has **'status' = 'enabled'** and **'availability' > 0** in table `products_meta`.

**2. My ideas**

- Do something like

```sql
SELECT products.id FROM products WHERE products.id in (SELECT products_meta.product_id FROM products_meta WHERE products_meta.key = 'status' AND products_meta.value = 'enabled')
```

but I don't exactly know, how to also require other key to be greater than 0

```sql
products_meta.key = 'availability' AND products_meta.value > 0
```

- Or use join method, like

```sql
SELECT products.id FROM products RIGHT JOIN products_meta WHERE (products_meta.key = 'status' AND products_meta.value = 'enabled')
```

and again, I don't know how to require other condition to be true

```sql
products_meta.key = 'availability' AND products_meta.value > 0
```

**3. Desired result**
I want to get from database result:
**products**

```
id | created_at | updated_at
----------------------------
1  | 10-06-2022 | 11-06-2022
```

and also all records from products_meta that matches product id that matches criteria
**products_meta**

```
id | product_id | key          | value
-----------------------------------------
1  | 1          | status       | enabled
2  | 1          | availability | 50
3  | 1          | name         | Bike
```

I looked through a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, and couldn't find example that matched my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an aggregation approach on the `products_meta` table here along with a join:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id
    FROM products_meta
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'status' THEN value END) = 'enabled' AND
           MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'availability' THEN value END) > 0
) pm
    ON pm.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: What about a performance?

Comment: We could look into indexing, but keep in mind that your `products_meta` table is not normalized and won't perform well generally.

Comment: What's the best way to normalize it? (I don't know sql very well)